# "^@" characters shown in SSH connection from OS X to Linux server

Tags: macos, ssh, iterm, escape-characters

When I SSH into a Linux server via iTerm on OS X, running a PHP script, 
there are some strange characters printed on the screen

[image: ^@ funny character]

What is this `^@` representing? These characters are not generated through the script, as you can see, they don't appear on every line.

Comment: Have you entered anything on your Mac while or before the script was executing? What is the script outputting? Do these characters appear for other scripts as well? Do you see these characters when logging in from another terminal or computer?

Comment: I connected to the server via iTerm, I guess is nothing to do with the Mac.

Comment: from this question, http://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-ths-symbol-with-vim suggesting `^@` is a null character

Comment: Yes, it is caret notation for the null character, but the question is why it even shows up. Do you get it for other scripts as well? Or when using another machine to connect to?

Comment: `tail -f` sometime might return this null character. It did appear in other scripts. Did not try on other machine. But ssh into another linux will return same null character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

By disabled the "When idle, send ASCII code: 0" will help